# NetBeans E-commerce Tutorial submit order error

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to learn javaee webdevelopment, I started by following [The NetBeans E-commerce Tutorial - Integrating Transactional Business Logic][1], I'm having a problem when I click submit order to enter data in the database, the orderID never gets updated and therefor I fail.

I did use em.flush() as explained:

> To understand why order.getId method returns null, consider what the
>   code is actually trying to accomplish. The getId method attempts to
>   get the ID of an order which is currently in the process of being
>   created. Since the ID is an auto-incrementing primary key, the
>   database automatically generates the value only when the record is
>   added. One way to overcome this is to manually synchronize the
>   persistence context with the database. This can be accomplished using
>   the EntityManager's flush method.

but still I get the orderid as 0.

```
private void addOrderedItems(CustomerOrder order, ShoppingCart cart) {

    em.flush();

    List<ShoppingCartItem> items = cart.getItems();

    // iterate through shopping cart and create OrderedProducts
    for (ShoppingCartItem scItem : items) {

        int productId = scItem.getProduct().getId();

        // set up primary key object
        OrderedProductPK orderedProductPK = new OrderedProductPK();
        orderedProductPK.setCustomerOrderId(order.getId());
        orderedProductPK.setProductId(productId);

        // create ordered item using PK object
        OrderedProduct orderedItem = new OrderedProduct(orderedProductPK);

        // set quantity
        orderedItem.setQuantity(scItem.getQuantity());

        em.persist(orderedItem);
    }
}
```

The problem was fixed. I did not give a value for the date, which should not be null. That's why I couldn't write to the database.

Comment: Post your entity and PK classes plus the exception stack trace.

Comment: I did post the entity above, please check them.

Comment: I'm not receiving an exception stack trace. I will post the controller code as well with the server output